# What syntax element do you hate most in a programming language you use frequently?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

No matter how much you love a programming language, there are always a few details in it that aren’t quite as nice as they could be.

In this question, I would like to specifically focus on **syntax elements.** In a programming language that you use frequently (perhaps your favourite programming language, or perhaps the one you are forced to use at work), which syntax element do you find most unreadable, unclear, inconvenient or unpleasant?

Comment: @Nathan Taylor, not for this question, but for [another question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/which-language-do-you-really-hate/2878#2878).

Comment: Did this question get modified? Because when I answered, it wasnt focused on "syntax elements"... I will have to modify my answer now.

Comment: @Talvi: No, it was about syntax right from the start.

Comment: @Timwi weird, it must be a case of 'answering a question thinking it was a different one' then.

Comment: If you can vote and think this is a useful question or it have useful answers below, please vote up. StackExchange sites need votes to build a good community. You can give 30 votes per day, don't waste them. Specially users with high reputation and low counting votes given please read this: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/393/asking-better-questions

Comment: It's amusing that the first answer containing C++ is about `switch` when everyone generally has only horrid stories to recount about it :)

Answer (score 39):

### Semicolon insertion in JavaScript.

I haven't really been bitten by it often, but it's just such a phenomenally bad idea it makes my head spin.

---

Here's the rules (from ECMA-262 Section 7.9)

1. When the program contains a token that is not allowed by the formal grammar, then a semicolon is inserted if (a) there is a line break at that point, or (b) the unexpected token was a closing brace.
2. When the end of a file is reached, if the program cannot be parsed otherwise, then a semicolon is inserted.
3. When a "restricted production" is encountered and contains a line terminator in a place where the grammar contains the annotation "[no LineTerminator here]", then a semicolon is inserted.

---

Example:

```
return 1; // returns 1

return
1; // returns undefined
```

Comment: JavaScript:The World's Most Misunderstood Programming Language ~Douglas Crockford

Comment: Yes, many expect JavaScript to be a "free-form language", but it isn't.

Comment: It makes sense once you realize that JavaScript was designed for creating HTML, which also has a long history of trying to interpret what your code "really means" when it isn't syntactically valid.  (Look up the Robustness Principle sometime--the biggest disaster in the history of computing.)

Comment: I don't actually think this was a mistake. The robustness principle is a good idea for languages that target non-programmers, who are more used to the flexible syntax of real world languages. A decent programmer's editor will prevent you from getting bitten by semi-colon insertion.

Comment: These types of errors, to me are a code-smell that the programmer is sloppy and has never worked with most formal "strict" languages that would normally cause a syntax error for leaving the semi-colon out.

Comment: Wohoo, finally someone else who also thinks Robustness Principle is a disaster that has made HTML the utter mess that it is.

Comment: I don't write the semicolons, at least given my coding style they make absolutely no difference. I agree that having both implicit semicolons, and implicit line continuation at the same time is a bad idea, but I would vouch for removing implicit line continuation.

Comment: Semicolon insertion isn't a bad idea in itself.  The bad idea was developing a syntax *almost* like C that would obviously mislead people into thinking semicolons should work like they do in C.

Answer (score 39):

### Java-bean syntax due to lack of C# properties

```
/**
 * Name of user
 */
private String name;

/**
 * Gets name of user
 * @return Name of user
 */
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

/**
 * Sets name of user. 
 * @param name
 */
public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

GAH!!!

Issues I have with this

- **Too much code** - Have a field that's documented, a getter method that's documented, and a setter method that's documented. This extremely basic example has **20** lines of code for a *single* property
- **Clutters method lists** - "Let me find that method, hand on: `getX`, `getY`, `getZ`, `getAnotherAnnoyingField`, `getWhyIHateJavaBeans`, `getThisIsVerbose`, `getGAH`... ah there it is, `hashCode`.
- **Multiple area's of documentation lead to poor, outdated, or missing documentation** - Annoying when trying to understand what code does
- **So annoying a 3rd party had to come up with a plugin to do this easily** - [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/), [Shark](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shark/), among others.

Comment: You can generate the beans easily with Eclipse. Just declare your attributes and go under "Source -> Generate Getters and Setters ...". Since eclipse is commonly used to program in Java, I don't see how "Too much code" and "So annoying a 3rd party had to come up with a plugin to do this easily" are a problem.

Comment: Once again when code is so verbose that it needs auto generating tools, something is wrong. I'm a NetBeans guy, but it also has the ability to auto generate getters and setters. But Javadoc falls out of syn, it's still verbose, it still clutters javadoc, etc

Comment: If you need getters for everything then something is wrong with the *client* code.

Comment: Having getters and setters breaks encapsulation. The field *might as well* be `public`. Members should be private and should be manipulated sensibly by the class with higher-level logic, *not* with getters and setters from client code.

Comment: @greyfade: If it's public, you can't easily change what the setting code does (you'll have to change all code that sets the field from the outside).

Comment: @greyfade: In theory you might be right, but in practice you're going to need getters and setters, just use them sparsely. You could find a lot of them even in Fowler's books on patterns and refactoring.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: If it's public, it's wrong. If client code is using a setter, it's wrong. Members *should* be `private` unless you've got a very good reason otherwise.

Comment: Java has no metaprogramming, and that may be the reason Java looks "clean"

Comment: @greyfade I'm not saying you should automatically have getters and setters for all fields, but there are many valid use cases for other code directly setting the value of a field, in which case setters are obviously better than public fields.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: I would argue that if you have a setter or a public field *at all*, it's a sign that your class is doing *too much* or that it's holding on to information that it shouldn't have. Worse, if your client code is modifying the class' members at such a low level, it's abusing that class. Classes should do only and exactly one thing, and it should abstract all of its state from its interface. No client code should be aware of any portion of that class' state, except to explicitly break the encapsulation.

Comment: @SHiNKiROU: Java looks clean? I've never heard that one before! My main gripe with Java is the fact that seemingly simple thing takes dozens of lines of code I need to mentally ignore.

Comment: @greyfade, you cannot specify public fields in interfaces - hence you must use getters and setters.

Comment: @configurator, have a look at Go.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: IMO, if you're using an interface that way, you're using it wrong. An interface should expose no knowledge of data, only an interface to logic. A concrete class should have data, but should not expose knowledge of it.

Comment: @greyfade, at SOME point you need to provide a way to let one class access information in another class.  If you dislike get/set, how would you do it then?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: *IF* I had one class that required access to a specific value held by another class, I would reconsider the design of my classes - I probably did something wrong; perhaps the other class should not be holding this value to begin with. If, on the other hand, it's specific functionality *relating* to a value that I require, then I'd consider adding this functionality to the other class *or* a new wrapper class. Very, very painfully rarely have I come across the situation where I needed to expose a value with a getter/setter. More usually, inheritance is the answer.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: In general, when a class needs to hold data, the class' *job* is to protect that data from outside interference: Its interface exposes only functionality, not data; a setter implies that my class is missing needed functionality (like a function that mutates the stored value) and a getter implies that the class has too much responsibility (someone else should be holding this value). In all other cases, a simple class with no interface and public members is the only reasonable choice (that is, getters and setters are unjustified).

Answer (score 32):

### Whitespace Sensitivity.

Python annoys me in this respect.  I mean, I indent properly anyway, but it bugs me that I should *have* to.  Making presentation part of the syntax irks me.

Comment: you'll learn to love it

Comment: syntax *is* presentation

Answer (score 32):

### The `switch` statement (in C, C++, C#, Java, etc.)

Here is an example of why I find it highly inconvenient:

```
switch (someVariable)
{
    case 1:
        int i = something();
        doSomething(i);
        break;

    case 2:
        int i = somethingElse();
        doSomethingElse(i);
        break;
}
```

This doesn’t compile because the variable `i` is redeclared in the same scope. This seems like a minor detail, but it bites me really often. I can add curly brackets to mitigate it, but it would have been nice if the curly brackets had been mandatory part of the syntax, and there was no redundant extra level of indentation. I also really hate having to write the extra `break`. This would be much nicer:

```
switch (someVariable)
case 1
{
    int i = something();
    doSomething(i);
}
case 2
{
    int i = somethingElse();
    doSomethingElse(i);
}
default
{
    ...
}
```

This makes it look more like an `if`/`else` chain, which is a good thing because it is semantically similar too. At least in C# it would still not be the same thing however, because in a `switch` statement the order of the case labels doesn’t matter, but in an `if`/`else` it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, your improved syntax does away with what is, arguably, switch's biggest feature in most of these languages: Fall-through. "Duff's Device" in C is a perfect example of the value of this particular "mis-feature." It is also common in C-like languages to use fall-through in interpreters and similar programs.

Comment: No, it doesn’t do away with it. It only requires that it be made more explicit (using a `goto` or similar), as is already the case in C#.

Comment: @greyfade: Any code using duff's device in C needs to die a horrible death. Compilers make better decisions about these kinds of things than you do.

Comment: Yes, `goto` is waaay better than fall-through. Though both pale in comparison to the shear awesomeness of `longjmp()`...

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yet I still find cases where complex logic is simplified by using fall-through. Cases where multiple values need to map to the same behavior. Cases where two values require the same behavior, but one with a preamble. Maybe the problem is that C and C++ only support switching on types convertible to `int`, but that doesn't change the fact that it's *useful*. Calling this a *bad* feature is short-sighted.

Comment: @Mr. C: Be careful not to criticise someone for something they didn’t say. It is useful to be able to jump to another case label in a way that is *equivalent to fall-through*. It doesn’t mean that the language should allow you to use `goto` to jump anywhere you want.

Comment: @Tirawi: I *think* what you're arguing for is explicit fall-through vs. implicit fall-through. However, that's not a fair description of `goto` in C#'s switch: you can jump backwards, skip over cases, etc... In short, it's a slightly-constrained form of the `goto` familiar to users of many other languages - so if you *wanted* to do the same in C, you *could*... Of course, if you want to be explicit, there are plenty of other ways to do so: code in function calls instead of case clauses, jump tables, polymorphism... So my first thought is that perhaps you shouldn't be using switch *at all*...

Comment: I so much agree with this answer, for C#. There is no fall-through in C#, so having all the case section be a single scope makes completely no sense, and often causes problems. I always place {} blocks inside my cases precisely for this reason, and would love it if that were enforced. (And then of course all the colons and other useless syntax removed.) For C, the existing form is fine. It fits the C style.

Comment: Because of the halting problem, C# compiler assumes that block is reachable. `switch { case }` is a bad construct overall. You must repeat `break;` many times. Except the Ruby  version is better. I also hated about how switch cases are indented: switch {-->case: } or switch {-->case:-->-->break }

Comment: @greyfade: Delphi gets around the multiple value issue by simply allowing multiple indices in the case: `case Foo of 1,3: Result := 'odd'; 2,4: Result := 'even' end;`.

Comment: Switches are screwy, but insanely useful. Like others here, I use fall-through rather regularly (but always comment it), but I agree that the lack of a default case-level block is annoying. And that switches tend to give you rediculously deep indentation.

Comment: @jkerian: Now imagine `break` was the default and only fallthrough needed to be specified. No more need to remember to comment it! :)

Comment: @Mr. C: I don't really see what the problem is with a forward-jumping `goto` in a C# `select` statement.  I mean, a `break` is already a form of jump statement anyway, much like goto.  I do agree that backwards-jumping gotos should generally be avoided, but that's the programmers fault for writing messy code.  I do think that C#'s way of dealing with switch statements is better than C++'s, because at least in C# you avoid accidental fallthrough.

Comment: You are missing the point of compound statements. Any branching construct in C can be followed by a single statement - this can be just a single semicolon, a simple statement terminated by a semicolon, or a copound statement enclosed in curly braces. If switch case construct mandated the curly braces, then it will become inconsistent with if-else, for, while etc.

Comment: @aufather: Obviously the curlies wouldn’t have to be mandatory for single statements.

Comment: @TimGoodman: I'm not complaining about goto. It's useful, sometimes... And as you note, it's the responsibility of the programmer to avoid it when a cleaner solution exists. But goto in C# switch statements is largely orthogonal to fall-through: you can use goto in C to do the same thing, if you desire. I suggest that the bigger mistake is cramming so much code into `case`es that fall-through isn't immediately obvious, regardless of whether implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 27):

## Array Declarations in VB.NET

I always manage to forget that when initializing fixed arrays in VB.NET, you're specifying the upper bound of the array and **not** the number of elements like in C/C++, PHP, or Java.  Besides VB6 (we won't go there...), I can't think of another language that does it this way:

```
Dim myArray(20) as Integer  '# Creates an array with 21 elements,
                            '# indexed from 0 to 20
```

Comment: I think all the BASIC languages do this...I know taht orginal BASIC and QBasic do.

Comment: OMG that is truly horrendous.... +1

Answer (score 24):

### VB6 - Separate Variable Declaration and Assignment

Most languages let you declare a variable and assign it in one line of code; VB6, on the other hand, forces you to use two.

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 0

Dim derpderp as Collection
Set derpderp = new Collection
```

You can use a colon to put two commands on one line, but it quickly turns messy in actual code.

```
Dim i as Integer: i = 0
Dim derpderp as Collection: Set derpderp = new Collection
```

Comment: +1 for having to use VB6 as your most frequent language.

Comment: I use it daily..sob.

Comment: Doesn't Pascal have a similar syntax? I always thought it was nasty.

Comment: There's a special case: if you `Dim Hurp As New Collection`, if you access `Hurp` when it refers to `Nothing`, it will be magically initialized before the access.  If you explicitly set it to `Nothing` and touch it again, it gets resurrected... gasp!

Comment: @Jeffery Hantin - That's actually completely different.  You then have VB6 checking to see if your object actually exists every time it's called (it's declared as a `New Collection`), which could lead to significant overhead on large applications.  I'd much rather manage everything myself.

Comment: It's been years since I used VB6, but I thought you could do something like `Dim x = 0, y = 1, z = 2 as Integer`, no?

Comment: @Carson Myers: No.

Comment: +1million for Derp.  Derp de derp de tiddly tum de derp.

Answer (score 24):

### Commenting in CSS

`//` doesn't comment out lines of code like it does in many other languages, like PHP and Javascript. Although `/* this is commented out */` works, I prefer to use `//`.

Its a nuisance, because half the time I forget I am editing CSS and then have to go back and fix the error.

Comment: You would of thought in this day and age that raw CSS would be considered object code.

Comment: // works just fine to comment out CSS.  I do it all the time.  All I'm really doing is typing garbage.  but it seems to work by skipping the unparseable line.

Comment: @MVCylon If you use // to comment out a line, anything after that following line also is skipped. {within that specific style} In other words, it FAILS because those lines should not be skipped.

Answer (score 20):

### PHP - consistent ordering of arguments

PHP has a number of handy functions for doing pretty much every operation you could think of on an array or string. Many of these operations require using both a `$needle` and a `$haystack`, but different functions take them in different orders. Which function requires which arguments is one of those facts my brain refuses to absorb, no matter how often I come across them!

Take the functions [in_array](http://ie.php.net/in_array) and [strstr](https://www.php.net/strstr):

```
// Check whether $needle occurs in array $haystack
bool in_array (mixed $needle, array $haystack [, bool $strict])

// Check whether $needle is a substring of $haystack
string strstr (string $haystack, mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle=false])
```

Funnily enough, PHP seems to be internally consistent with these orderings in that all string functions seem to use `$haystack, $needle` while array functions are the other way around, but this can take a bit of getting used to for someone new to PHP. There's a good [post on ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/blog/entry/a_haystack_in_a_needle/) talking about this particular quirk in more detail, as well as a [discussion on the PHP bugs list](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37088), which features a very short response from the PHP team!

> **helly@php.net**
>
> Use a decent IDE then.

Comment: It's easier to remember the order `$needle`, `$haystack` as it reminds the way of saying _find a needle in a haystack_.

Comment: Protip: in array functions, needle comes first. in string functions, haystack comes first.

Comment: I love the name `strstr`. So beautifully meaningless.

Comment: Just read the linked entry in PHP's bugtracker. Seriously, wtf? oO Imho consistency is a valid issue for any API and just responding with "use a decent IDE then" is just not a valid reply. At least it could have been worded less inflammatory by the devs.

Comment: @configurator: PHP got that name from C.

Comment: @dan04: You say that like it makes it a better name.

Comment: This is actually not a syntax element. Since they are just functions... I've found such inconsistencies in almost every language, they are almost impossible to avoid I think.

Comment: @Inca: I disagree - PHP is especially bad about this. Most of the POSIX C functions that PHP imports (`str*`) are self-consistent. But then PHP mixes and matches with all other functions, often nonsensically.

Comment: Honestly, what drives me crazy about this is that it shouldn't be a function at all! It should just be a method: $haystack->find($needle). Done deal.

Answer (score 19):

### Python

`self` parameter in instance method definitions

Comment: In a classmethod, it's usually named cls and using self goes against convention.

Comment: It actually make sense if you think about it. It's the same as declaring a private method in other languages, the self parameter is just explicit in python where it's implicit in other languages. If you want it to be implicit add the @classmethod decorator before the method declaration. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod. Learning the details of how this works will give you some insight as to how it's done in other languages implicitly.

Comment: I understand the reasons and why it is left there http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html but I still don't like it

Comment: @Evan Plaice: 'self parameter is just explicit in python where it's implicit in other languages' That's only one part of the story. The other part is python being weekly typed. Together it's terrible, forgetting `self` happens to easily and costs time.

Comment: @maaartinus Then add a classmethod decorator to your instance methods. Has nothing do with 'weakly typed'. It just makes the relationship between static methods/functions (no 'self' parameter) and instance methods (includes 'self') obvious. An instance method isn't aware of it's parent class unless you give it a reference to do so. In other languages the distinguishing characteristic I outlined is just hidden behind syntactic sugar.   If I had a choice to do it all over I would have started learning OOP in Python first.

Comment: @Evan Plaice: I never said the two things are logically related. Just that together they lead to errors not happening in other languages.

Answer (score 18):

### Java

Period.  Full stop.  End of story.

Where to start?  Oh, I know where to start: Java’s insanely complicated and ugly and stupid  and **inherently broken** generics.  Need I say more? :(  Ok fine, then: **type erasure**.

Then there’s non-deterministic resource management.  Kewl feetcher!

What’s next up?  Oh yeah: [Java’s stupid regexes](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#4vlodpF_ctc/nexus/nexus-utils/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/util/Inflector.java&q=%66%75%63%6b%69%6e%67%20lang%3ajava&sa=N&cd=225&ct=rc) are my most irritating, seething beef. I cannot count how many times I’ve been hosed by not having enough backslashes.  This is even worse than not having access to any Unicode properties from this millennium — which is complete bull.  **Ten fricking years out of date!!!** Completely useless.  Trash it.

Then there’s the bug that the character class shortcuts don’t work on non-ASCII. What a royal pain!  And don’t even consider using `\p{javaWhiteSpace}`; it doesn’t do the right thing with several very common Unicode whitespace code points.

Did you know there’s a `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}` property?  Whatwhatatat wereere  they thinkinking? So glad they got such smart peepers wurkin on dis tough.

Ever tried to use the CANON_EQ flag? Do you know that **really** does, and what it **doesn’t** do?  How about so-called “Unicode case”?  A bunch of normal casing things just don’t work at all.

Then they make it hard to write maintainable regexes.  Java still hasn’t figured out how to write multiline strings, so you end up writing insane things like this:

```
    "(?= ^ [A-Z] [A-Za-z0-9\\-] + $)      \n"
  + "(?! ^ .*                             \n"
  + "    (?: ^     \\d+      $            \n"
  + "      | ^ [A-Z] - [A-Z] $            \n"
  + "      | Invitrogen                   \n"
  + "      | Clontech                     \n"
  + "      | L-L-X-X                      \n"
  + "      | Sarstedt                     \n"
  + "      | Roche                        \n"
  + "      | Beckman                      \n"
  + "      | Bayer                        \n"
  + "    )      # end alternatives        \n"
  + ")          # end negated lookahead   \n"
```

What are all those newlines?  Oh, just Java stupidity. They used Perl comments, not Java comments (**idiots!**) which go till end of line.  So if you don’t put those `\n`’s there, you chop off the rest of your pattern.  Duh and double duh!

Don’t use regexes in Java: you’ll just end up wanting to smash things, it’s all so painful and broken. I can’t believe people put up with this.  [Some don’t](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#4vlodpF_ctc/nexus/nexus-utils/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/util/Inflector.java&q=%66%75%63%6b%69%6e%67%20lang%3ajava&sa=N&cd=225&ct=rc).

Then we can start talking about Java’s idiot nonsense with encodings. First, there’s the fact that the default platform encoding is always some lame 8-bit encoding even though Java’s charchars are Unicode.  Then there’s how they don’t raise an exception on an encoding error.  You’re guaranteed to get crap.  Or how about this:

```
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out) 
          Creates an OutputStreamWriter that uses the default character encoding.
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, Charset cs) 
          Creates an OutputStreamWriter that uses the given charset.
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, CharsetEncoder enc) 
          Creates an OutputStreamWriter that uses the given charset encoder.
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName) 
          Creates an OutputStreamWriter that uses the named charset.
```

What’s the difference?  Did you know that *only one* of those will raise an exception if you have an encoding error?  The rest just muzzle them.

Then there’s the idiocy of Java chars not being sufficient to hold a character!  What the hell are they thinking?  That’s why I call them charchars.  You have to write code like this if you expect it work right:

```
private static void say_physical(String s) { 
    System.out.print("U+");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%X", s.codePointAt(i));
        if (s.codePointAt(i) > Character.MAX_VALUE) { i++; }  // UG!
        if (i+1 < s.length()) { System.out.printf("."); }
    }
}
```

And *who* ever thinks to do that? Next to nobody.

How many characters are there in `"\uD83D\uDCA9"`?  One or two? Depends on how you count them.  The regex engine of course deals with logical characters, so a pattern `^.$` will succeed and a pattern `^..$` will fail.  This insanity is demonstrated here:

```
String { U+61, "\u0061", "a" }  =~ /^.$/ => matched.
String { U+61, "\u0061", "a" }  =~ /^..$/ => failed.
String { U+61.61, "\u0061\u0061", "aa" }  =~ /^.$/ => failed.
String { U+61.61, "\u0061\u0061", "aa" }  =~ /^..$/ => matched.
String { U+DF, "\u00DF", "ß" }  =~ /^.$/ => matched.
String { U+DF, "\u00DF", "ß" }  =~ /^..$/ => failed.
String { U+DF.DF, "\u00DF\u00DF", "ßß" }  =~ /^.$/ => failed.
String { U+DF.DF, "\u00DF\u00DF", "ßß" }  =~ /^..$/ => matched.
String { U+3C3, "\u03C3", "σ" }  =~ /^.$/ => matched.
String { U+3C3, "\u03C3", "σ" }  =~ /^..$/ => failed.
String { U+3C3.3C3, "\u03C3\u03C3", "σσ" }  =~ /^.$/ => failed.
String { U+3C3.3C3, "\u03C3\u03C3", "σσ" }  =~ /^..$/ => matched.
String { U+1F4A9, "\uD83D\uDCA9", "" }  =~ /^.$/ => matched.
String { U+1F4A9, "\uD83D\uDCA9", "" }  =~ /^..$/ => failed.
String { U+1F4A9.1F4A9, "\uD83D\uDCA9\uD83D\uDCA9", "" }  =~ /^.$/ => failed.
String { U+1F4A9.1F4A9, "\uD83D\uDCA9\uD83D\uDCA9", "" }  =~ /^..$/ => matched.
```

That idiocy is all because you can’t write the perfectly reasonable `\u1F4A9`, nor of course do you get any warning that you can’t do that. It just does the wrong thing.

Stoooopid.

While we’re at it, the whole `\uXXXX` notation is congenitally brain dead. The Java preprocessor (**yes, you heard me**) gets at it before Java does, so you are forbidden from writing perfectly reasonable things like `"\u0022"`, because by the time Java sees that, its preprocessor has turned it into `"""`, so you lose.  Oh wait, **not** if it’s in a regex! So you can use `"\\u0022"` just fine.

Riiiiiiiight!

Did you know there’s no way in Java to do an `isatty(0)` call?  You aren’t even allowed to think such thoughts.  It wouldn’t be good for you.

And then there’s the whole classpath abomination.

Or the fact that there’s no way to specify the encoding of your Java source file **in that same source file** so you don’t lose it?  Once again I demand to know: **WHAT THE HELL WERE THEY THINKING‽‽‽**

Stop the madness!  I can’t believe people put up with this garbage.  It’s a complete joke. I’d rather be a Walmart greeter than suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous Java insanity.  It’s all broken, and they not only can’t fix it, they **won’t** fix it.

This by the same foxy-grapey people who prided themselves on a language that made it illegal to have a `printf()` function. Gee, **that** sure worked out real well, didn’t it though!?

Sheer numbskulls. Bitch-slapping is too kind for them. If I wanted to program in assembler, I would. This is not a salvageable language. The emperor has no clothes.

We hates it.  We hates it **forever**. Let it die die **die**!

Comment: Haha, good one, I don't touch java because it's too unpolished like you describe. As for \uD83D... well I suppose a better way of saying this is that you'd rather strings were not UTF-16 but UTF-32 instead. If you accept UTF-16-ness then the regex do the right thing; it's the .length call that fucks up.

Comment: -1. With the exception of regexp comments and Unicode escapes, not a single one of the things you mentioned is a syntax element.

Comment: @Jörg, you want syntax? Ok fine: Java allows you to put control characters, include ESC and NUL, in identifiers.  WTH were they thinking???

Comment: @tchrist: Wow! If I ever write a Java program again, all my variables will have names consisting of varying numbers of backspace characters (`^H`) :)

Comment: So not handling Unicode characters above 0x10000 to your liking is in your top five list of Java problems? I think you're giving Java too much credit, there are bigger issues than that.

Comment: @Jaap, no, you’re right — those were just what was bothering me at that point in time. Insanity with generics is a much bigger problem, and there are of course lots and lots and lots of others. It’s also wicked that you need an `int` for arbitrary characters, not a `char`.

Comment: @tchrist, feeling better now?

Comment: +1 I would have also mentioned random/urandom bug on unix platforms to make whole picture more complete

Answer (score 16):

Function pointer declaration syntax in C and C++:

```
(int)(*f)(int, int);
```

That declares a function pointer named `f` whose pointee can take two `int`s and return an `int`.

I'd much prefer a syntax like this:

```
f: (int, int) => int
```

---

Say you want to declare a function pointer `g` whose pointee can take two `int`s and a function from `int` and `int` to `int`, and return an `int`.

With C or C++ notation, you'd declare it as:

```
(int)(*g)(int, int, int(int, int));
```

With the above-proposed notation same thing can be declared as:

```
g: (int, int, (int, int) => int) => int
```

Latter is much more intuitive IMO.

---

Aside: The programming language called OOC fixes this syntax (and various other syntactical issues in C and C++). Check out its homepage [here](http://ooc-lang.org/).

Comment: Agree, some "plain C" / "C++" doesn't support it, or support it with different syntax. A special syntax, helps indicate when a programming language feature is supported. That's why C# added "delegate" syntax.

Comment: Delegates are not only syntactic sugar because they also store the object (contrary to C++ member function pointers, that have even worse syntax than regular function pointers)

Answer (score 14):

Verbosity in Java.

ie:

```
public static final int
```

Comment: Compared to? (15 chars)

Comment: @TheLQ: Instead of `private final int` it could have been `int`.

Comment: @Jonas then `public static final int` could have been `public static int`?

Comment: @zneak: Or how about `public { int counter; double lat; double lng; }` - a public block.

Comment: Compared to: `const int` for instance.

Comment: "public static final int x = 4;" compared to "x = 4" in Haskell.

Comment: @Oscar I think the final means that it can't be overwritten in another class (I am not sure, that's what it does in actionscript 3)

Comment: [Public static void](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kj5ApnhPAE), Rob Pike complaining about the verbosity of Java.

Comment: That's not verbosity. Try writing `a+(b*c)/d*e+f/g^20` using `BigInteger` in Java. Why does this language not allow operator overloading?

Comment: Scala to the rescue: `val` :-)

Comment: @MAK Same reason it doesn't support multiple inheritance: to protect programmers from themselves. (I love Java, but...)

Comment: @Michael: programmers who need to be protected from themselves at this cost can best protect themselves (and reduce the pain for everyone else) by not programming at all :D.

Answer (score 12):

### \we\wouldnt\fix\our\parser namespace syntax in PHP

The syntax is not only ugly, it leads to confusion when newer developers have to think about namespaces in strings.  (PHP interpolates backslashes in double-quoted strings as escape sequences.  Trying to represent a namespace like `\you\should\never\do\that` in a double-quoted string instead of a single-quoted string will lead to newlines, tabs and disaster.)

Comment: Yeah, someone thought of a better::way to do this, but PHP insist that every operator must be different. I am curious as to what the misuse issue is here though.

Comment: Agree. PHP require namespaces, but that syntax screw it up

Answer (score 9):

I despise the fact that curly braces can be optional after an if/while/for statement.

Especially when I see code like,

```
if (...)
    for(...)
        ... One line of stuff ...
```

Please just put the braces in and be done with it.

Comment: Hmm.. this depends. For "Abort Ifs" which merely check a condition and return an error code (or throw an exception), I'd much rather not see the braces.

Comment: Or `if (condition) while (...) { /* multiple lines here */ }`

Comment: I would agree if you limited yourself to extreme multi-level cases, but your statement is too blanket. There is great utility in the ability to have short forms for simple, single-statement ifs and loops.

Comment: My rule: only if a statement requires multiple substatements *or if it contains such a statement* should it be wrapped in braces. Thus `for (...) while (...) if (...) { x(); y(); }` is better rewritten as `for (...) { while (...) { if (...) { x(); y(); } } }`, with appropriate indentation, of course.

Comment: I'm rather the opposite -- I despise people who insist on putting in braces when they're completely unnecessary. Just learn to program.

Comment: If you're nesting constructs like that, there's a case for refactoring to a method anyway.

Comment: I really like the brackets even in single if statements. It makes me follow the flow of a program better.

Comment: +1. Missing brackets lead sometimes to terrible mistakes. Like when once, refactoring the code `if (IsDirectoryEmpty(directory)) Delete(directory);`, my colleague thought that it would be wise to log the directory removal first, like this: `if (IsDirectoryEmpty(directory)) Log("Message here..."); Delete(directory);` It was fun when it removed a non-empty directory with some useful files, requiring to spend an hour restoring incremental backups.

Comment: If you want one-liner `if`s, it's fine to leave the braces out, but only in that case, and you can have only **one** function in these. `if ($_POST['myform']) echo 'Form data: '; echo $_POST['myform']; else echo 'Form is empty!';` will echo `'Form data: '` if the form isn't empty, echoes the form data anyway, and `else` causes a syntax error.

Comment: @MainMa: If the original statement was in a single line, then it's his fault. Point. If it wasn't... well... use a proper editor which indents it properly. I never ever use braces in one-liner and it never happens to me.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, AMEN! Finally someone who agrees.

Comment: -1 This is a great feature. Removes 1-2 unnecessary lines of code without relying on whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

### VBScript Doesn't Have Logical Operators

Unlike nearly every sensible language, VBScript uses bitwise operators instead of logical operators. What does this mean in practice? Well, as [Eric Lippert points out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx):

```
If Blah = True Then Print "True!" Else Print "False!"
```

and

```
If Blah Then Print "True!" Else Print "False!"
```

are NOT the same in VBScript!

Even worse, though, this means that there is no short-circuit evaluation in VBScript so that the following statement will *crash* your program if `Blah` is `Nothing`

```
If (Not Blah Is Nothing) And (Blah.Frob = 123) Then
...
```

That's right, VBScript will evaluate *both* parts of the AND comparison, even if the first one is false! Just let that sink in...

Comment: Until the day you've hunted a bug inside an `If x Then ... If Not x Then ... End If ... End If` and figured out that x is 2, you haven't really programmed in VB/VBScript.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: Following the discussion in the comments I decided to update this answer to explain myself better.**

I really hate the way function pointers look in C. Usually any variable declaration looks like a tuple of: `type varname;`
Function pointer declarations on the other hand look like a declaration of the function with * before the function name. I can accept this as a description of a pointer type, but in C this declares both the type and the name of a variable of that type. This looks inconsistent to me because type declarations are otherwise distinct from variable declarations. `struct myStruct{int X; int Y;}` only defines a type, it does not define a variable named `myStruct`. Likewise I see no reason for type declarations and variable declarations to be grouped into one *atomic* statement in function pointers, nor do I appreciate the deviation from the `type varname;` structure.

Someone pointed out that it's consistent with some spiral rule, and that may be the case, but the mark of a good syntax is that it is self explanatory and its internal logic is obvious. The spiral rule is not obvious by any means.

Comment: It's consistent with the rest of the language, so maybe your gripe is about the syntax of C declarators in general?  Do you prefer the syntax used in [Go](http://golang.org/doc/go_lang_faq.html#declarations_backwards)?

Comment: Consistent in what way? Usually it goes: type varname; And when we create a new composite type, like a struct, first comes the declaration, maybe with a typedef, and then we create a variable of that type. When we declare a function pointer, it's int (*foo)(int arg1, int arg2), which is then used as the type of an argument passed to a function: void newFoo(int (*foo)(int arg1, int art2)).... and as a variable: foo=a_compatible_func;
I think that a function declaration first, and then a var declaration next would be more consistent, like so: 
typedef int (*foo)(int, int) MyFoo;
MyFoo myfoo;

Comment: That's why you got `typedef`.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying that it shouldn't be defining a variable name at the same time. struct myStruct{XYZ} doesn't define a variable called myStruct, only a type is defined. But int (*foo)(int, int) actually defines a variable along with the type.

Comment: @EpsilonVector: I tend to agree that function pointer syntax is nasty, but there is a simple rule to follow that makes it easier to read. The clockwise spiral rule (perhaps you've seen it?): http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: I've always seen it called "inside-out", but clockwise spiral works too.  Function pointer syntax is consistent with arrays, which people rarely seem to have a problem with.

Comment: EpsilonVector: I'm not sure what you'd expect from a *pointer variable* declaration to declare other than the name of the variable.

Comment: @EpsilonVector: I realise it's an ugly syntax, but I don't think it's any more inconsistent than array declaration syntax: `int x[42];`.  The `[42]` part comes after the variable name, just like the parameter type list does when declaring a function pointer.

Comment: @j_randon_hacker Hmm... I guess that's why Java made it int[] varname then. To be honest I never noticed that inconsistency, I always read it as "int x times 42"... but you have a point.

Answer (score 6):

In/out arguments. I'm all for in arguments (good thing I am), out arguments are fine too, but an argument that must convey these two states pisses me off.

What I target here are functions that take input from a parameter then overwrite that input with some output. It's okay to pass an object by reference to update it. But, mostly for primitive types, taking an object, use it, then change it completely, is not right by me. You shouldn't change the *meaning* of the argument through an inout.

Comment: What language do you have in mind?  If C# then I would disagree that it's annoying because it's always explicit (unlike in C++.)  Also I don't know of any mainstream language where your are forced to declare arguments as in/out.

Comment: @finnw I've never seen a language where you *had* to say `in` for `in` arguments either, I'm just talking about them. Also, in my opinion, _nothing_ can excuse an in/out argument, and making them explicit does not relieve the pain. There should be no reason to have to initialize a local variable with a value helpful to the function, and have this same variable then suddenly contain whatever the function decided to put there. These two should be distinct. Always.

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear there.  I meant to say "I don't know of any language where all arguments are implicitly in
+out" i.e. you are not forced to use that feature, but there are legitimate use cases (e.g. updating a `struct` where the new value depends on the value of another field of the same `struct`.)

Comment: @finnw Objects passed by reference (like instances of `class` objects in C#) being modified by a function are fine to me. Aside that I dislike non-constant structs, passing a `struct` with the `ref` keyword to update it is okay, too. What I really hate is when input is __overwritten__ with output. The best example I can think of is Berkeley socket's `accept` function: it needs a `socklen_t*` argument that, on input, must contain the size of the `struct sockaddr*` you've passed; and on output, will contain the number of bytes that have been written to it. This should be criminal.

Comment: I agree that is bad (IIRC some Win32 I/O functions do the same) but that is misuse of the feature (the function call changes the meaning of the passed-in variable, not just its value) and it does not mean the feature itself is bad.

Comment: This answer seems off-topic because it is not about **syntax**.

Comment: @zneak: Just FWIW, in Ada you explicitly declare arguments as `in`, `out`, or `inout`.

Answer (score 6):

### Semicolons in VBScript - or the lack thereof

I spend all day working in languages that expect semicolons at the end of each line. Add one to the end of the line in VBScript and your code doesn't run anymore.

Comment: up-voting this, not because I particularly like semicolons, but because I really *hate* the way VB encourages *really long lines* by making linebreaks so inconvenient.

Answer (score 6):

### Array declarations in C and C++.

Typically, a variable declaration is of the format `type variable_name`.  You can easily read those declarations in a left-to-right manner.  But `int foo[size]` looks at first like it's declaring `foo` as an int, and then you read further and see that foo's of type "array of integers."  `int[size] foo` reads much better.

And I also hate it when programmers declare pointers like this for a similar reason: `int *foo`.  For some reason I haven't figured out, that's the *typical* way it's written.

Comment: Re pointer declarations: they're written like that because the '*' binds to the variable name, not the type. So `int* a, b;` does *not* declare `a` and `b` as pointers; only `a` is. Hence it's better to write it as `int *a, b;` (or even better to write them as two declarations).

Comment: Good point.  It's too bad `*` doesn't bind to the type.

Comment: And this is to say nothing of function pointers... `void(int) *f;`? Nope: `void (*f)(int);`

Comment: In modern C++ there is very little need for pointers and arrays.

Comment: @zildjohn01: Isn't `void(*)(int) f;` also valid syntax for that?

Comment: Sorry, I must have hallucinated that. Apparently it's not.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: Although I +1ed this answer, I think that `int* a, b;` issue you mentioned is much more egregious.

Comment: Never thought of that but `int[10] foo` makes a lot more sense - especially when you consider `delete []`

Answer (score 5):

Redundant parameterization in Java:

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> foo = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

What other type parameterization does the compiler *think* `foo` could have?

Comment: I hope you are aware of Java's (limited) type inference?  `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> foo = Maps.newHashMap();`

Comment: Java 7: `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> foo = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Well it can have any type it wants, the types are erased anyway...

Comment: Lack of type inference, you mean?

Comment: `What other type parameterization does the compiler think foo could have?` - For whatever reason it things it's raw type - as if anybody sane would even mix raw and parametrized types.

Answer (score 5):

Since people have already complained about `=` vs. `==`, let me point out a much worse alternative. PL/I had both `:=` and `=`, *but* when something was "obviously" an assignment, it would let you get away with using `=` to do it. Using `:=` let you force something to be an assignment in a situation where the compiler would otherwise interpret it as a comparison.

Unfortunately, the compiler didn't always decided on things quite the way you might expect. Consider just one obvious example:

```
A = B = 0;
```

Now, to most people familiar with most "ordinary" languages, the meaning of this is pretty obvious -- assign 0 to both A and B. PL/I is just a bit...different though. For reasons known only to the (insane) designers of the language, the first `=` is interpreted as an assignment, but the second `=` is interpreted as a comparison. Therefore, this compares B to 0, and then assigns the result of that comparison to A (following the C-style convention that "false" results in 0 and "true" in 1).

So, if B was 0, then A becomes 1. Otherwise, A becomes 0. In other words, rather than assigning the same value to A and B, this actually ensures that A *cannot* have the same value as B.

Bottom line: even though the C/C++/PHP style initially *seems* like a pain, the alternative is much worse<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>Well, technically, there's another alternative: Pascal style, where `=` always means comparison and assignment always requires `:=`. After using that for a while, it's pretty obvious (at least to me) that assignment is enough more common than comparison that if you're going to require extra "stuff" to disambiguate the two, you should definitely keep assignments clean and simple and require the extra "grunge" on comparisons, not vice versa.

Comment: I'd even propose to use `==` for equality and `:=` for assignment. This way you have more to type, but avoiding the lonely `=` helps to avoid bugs.

Comment: @maartinus: at least to me, that sounds like the absolute worst possibility, but such is life...

Answer (score 3):

### Perl

1. I wish Perl let me write `if($x < 10) do_something();`. At the moment, you have to write that as either `do_something() if($x < 10);` or as `if($x < 10) { do_something(); }`.

Comment: `do_something() if ($x < 10);` isn't that bad.

Comment: It isn't, and in many cases is much cleaner than `if(..) ...` to boot, as you can get all the expressions to line up on the right. But there's times I really want to say `if($x < 10) do_something();`, and it's unfortunate that Perl won't let me.

Comment: It's unfortunate until you write
`if ($x<10) do_something();  and_call_me();`  and then wonder why you never get a call.  I wish C and family would require the braces, to prevent that type of error.

Comment: @AShelly: Ah, I never thought of it that way! Thanks.

Comment: @AShelly: or why you always get a call, actually.

Comment: @zneak, you caught me.  But the correct version doesn't flow so nicely.  Call it poetic license.

Comment: @zneak Except no `else`s. (I wish it has `EXPR1 if COND else EXPR2` like Python has)

Comment: @SHiNKiROU: Perl seems to have a ternary operator, though.

Comment: `$x < 10 && do_something();`. Also, sometimes you can nice things with a `when` construct.

Answer (score 3):

`reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>` in c++.  This operation is useful in dealing with foreign APIs and ensuring numerical precision, why should it be such a pain to type and so ugly to look at?

Comment: It's ugly to remind you that you should strive to write code that doesn't require it. :)

Comment: To me that's a good theoretical computer science kind of argument, but in my experience, it's too useful to avoid  (However, much of my experience is plain old C, so I probably have a bias).

Comment: It's not really a theoretical CS argument: Using a `reinterpret_cast` in C++ is a very strong code smell. 99% of the time, when you are about to use it, chances are, you shouldn't need to - you probably did something wrong. The other 1% of the time, you're interfacing with C. `reinterpret_cast` breaks the type system to make something work when it otherwise can't. That's usually a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

The [for ... in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) construct in JavaScript and the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct in PHP when looping over arrays. Both of them make it easier to write bugs than correct code.

Comment: If I have to write extra code to use them safely, they're easier to use wrong in my book. For ... in requires extra checks to make sure you're not iterating over objects from the prototype, and foreach requires you to clean up references afterwards or risk overwriting the last value in the array.

Comment: the foreach with changing references (& operator) is a famous bug...

Comment: I'm confused, I thought it was common knowledge that the "for..in" construct in javascript is broken... why is this offensive?

Answer (score 2):

Pointers of arrays or arrays of pointers in C/C++. I am still confused about these.

Comment: Read the type backwards. `int[]*` is a pointer to an array of integers, and `int*[]` is an array of pointers to integers. Works well with `const`s too: `int* const` is a constant pointer to integers, whereas `const int*` and `int const*` are pointers to constant integers (or to integer constants).

Comment: @zneak: "Right to left" doesn't work, see the mentioned ["clockwise spiral" / "inside out"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/501/what-syntax-element-do-you-hate-most-in-a-programming-language-you-use-frequently/511#511) rule.

Comment: Or, just use *typedefs* and there's no confusion.

Comment: In modern C++ there is very little need for pointers and arrays.

Comment: There's no such thing as a pointer to an array in C.

Comment: @tchrist: Not true. `int (*p)[10];` declares `p` to be a pointer to an array of 10 ints.  If `sizeof (int) == 4`, then `p++` will advance `p` by 40.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that Python relies on text formatting.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript/Java etc, equals comparison, eg if(a==1)**

How many times do I write if(a=1) ?

As a human I read that perfectly. But the darn interpreter/compiler says, "hey I'll assign 1 to a, then check if a is equal to 1, and would you believe it yes it is!

Drives me up the wall.

if(a==1) is far less readable, and the interpreter/compiler should know what I mean anyway; many other lesser languages (VB) have been working it out successfully for hundreds of years.

Comment: What is `if (a = true)` supposed to mean?

Comment: Assignment just shouldn't return a value. It's sometimes useful, but in most cases it's just a pain in the neck.

Comment: in Javascript JSLint will catch that one for you.

Comment: The trouble is, assignment in conditions can be useful. I find <tt>while( element = list->next() )</tt> quite legible. So I am not sure I would like te have it removed.

Comment: @Tom: It means you don't understand booleans.  If you meant `if (a == true)`, just write `if (a)`.  If you meant `a = true`, then the `if` statement is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Verbosity in Java anonymous classes. Will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: Unless you want more than one method.

Answer (score 0):

`structPointer->member` in C/C++ . May be good for reading someone else's code, but I don't like it. Two characters instead of one... what a waste of space!

Comment: Unfortunately, it must be distinguished from `.`, which applies to members of a non-pointer object. Ambiguous syntax is bad, mmmkay?

Comment: @greyfade: Yep!  Because the compiler can't *possibly* use its type system rules to tell when you're using a pointer-to-struct type and apply the dereference implicitly.  Nope, that's crazy talk!  (And yet it can still somehow give you an error message when you get it wrong.)  There's nothing ambiguous about the syntax.  It's just C being a braindead mess, as usual.  Delphi does implicit dereferences just fine, if you're actually working in dark corners that require pointers-to-records, so it can certainly be done without confusing a parser...

Comment: @Mason: What about cases like `shared_ptr`, where `->` accesses the contained type and `.` accesses properties of the `shared_ptr` itself? I'm sorry, but I completely disagree here.

Comment: `X->Y` is (read: ought to be) sugar for `(*X).Y` anyhow.

Comment: could be worse. Could be PHP, where you have to use `->` to access members of _anything_.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I disagree. It's C++, not C. First, in C there should never have been `->` as it's useless there. Second, for your special case another syntax could be invented. --- @Mason Wheeler: Agreed, but Delphi is much more confused (just try to overload a function on DOUBLE and TDate and call it).

Comment: @maaartinus: The answer says C/C++.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I mean, there's no `shared_ptr` nor anything else in C, where both `.` and `->` could apply. So dot alone would be sufficient for C.

Comment: @maaartinus: Has there been anything I said contrary to that? I believe my comment clearly applies to C++ only. Personally, I find `identifier->` easier to read than `(*identifier).`, but that's more a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I'd suggest to always write `x.a`, no matter if dereferencing happens. For C it's sufficient, for C++ not always, but nearly always, and there could be a special syntax for such cases.

Comment: @maaartinus: Any code which relies that heavily on non-obvious order of operations is not code I will be writing.

Answer (score 0):

**Scala multi-line code in brackets**

For instance:

```
class Foo(
         val bar: String,
         val baz: Int,
         val bing: String,
         val bong: Boolean
 ) extends Model {
   // body here
 }
```

What you actually get from it is terrific. It generates the constructor and the getters and setters for you. But it sure is ugly and breaks all my mental models of how to indent code and basically leaves me feeling like I'm in a sort of bizarre sandwich with Java on one side and Lisp on the other. (Oh, wait... that is rather the point of Scala.)

Comment: I'm confused -- do you mean the portion in the parenthesis (`val bar` and so on) or the portion in curly braces (the part following `extends Model`)? (There are no brackets in that code)

Comment: The portion in the parentheses. I'm English. We refer to those as brackets, damnit, because in that situation they aren't serving a parenthetical role.

Comment: It doesn't look all that bad if indented this way: http://pastebin.com/h9qC8XGg

Comment: I find it more readable to write these constructor parameter lists horizontally, especially when I only have a few parameters.

Comment: Looks like a method to me. Like Simula. Good old school.

Answer (score 0):

### REGEX / `preg_match()` in PHP

Firstly, its completely different syntax than PHP uses. While the `preg_match()` function emulates regex quite excellently, I have to completely switch my mode of thinking to work with it.

Secondly, its just plain obscurification half the time. I usually have to quite literally take out a scratch pad and figure out WTF its doing half the time.

Besides, I program in PHP, not Perl. If I liked Perl, I would program in Perl. (no, sir I don't like it.)

To make matters worse, with the new PCRE delimiter format, you can practically use any character, which includes having to escape that same nested character, making the pattern **even more** obscure.

Sure, its great if you want to be cryptic.. or even efficient... but holy hell the amount of time it wastes to normally perform simple tasks.

Comment: The fact that you have your answer written with `PERL` in all caps tells me that you've never actually looked into the language at all and don't know anything about it.

Comment: PHP is sometimes too slow to do parsing any other way than with regexes.

Comment: @daenyth you are right, I haven't much, however I wouldn't say don't know *anything*. But what Joeri said is correct.. it is needed occasionally and is the one thing that throws a monkeywrench in coding PHP without having to reference docs much.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but how come no one mentioned.

## CODE NUGGETS

`<% %>` <-- Regular

`<%= %>` <-- Buffalo style

`<%:%>` <-- extra crispy

Answer (score -1):

$this->... in PHP ... unnecessary, looks bad and considerably slows down "quick-grasp-on-short-glance" ([my closed thread on SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5118600/562440)).

Comment: as optional is useful, as mandatory is unnecesary...

Answer (score -1):

SSIS - SQl Server I hate everything about the Expression Builder. I already know how to write these types of conditions in t-sql. Why can't they Expression builder use the same syntax t-SQl would use (especially The equivalent to the CASE statement)? Or let me write t-sql statements instead of creating stupid wierd expressions. And why am I stuck doing complex conditions in a form that only allows me to use one line so I am in scroll bar hell?

Comment: This answer seems to be all about UI and has nothing to do with syntax elements.

Answer (score -2):

**& && | || in C**

C++ has rectified it to some extend with explicit "and" "or" keywords. Many a bugs and torn hair could have been avoided in C if logical operations and bitwise operations weren't so hard to differentiate.

Comment: The `and` and `or` keywords are provided by `<iso646.h>`. `#include` that your C programs and that's a complete non-issue. C++ is also required to provide the same header.

Comment: I've never ever had trouble distinguishing the two...

Comment: That's nonsense, it's trivial to remember and optically very different. Using the keyword `and` is even a bigger nonsense. Without reading the definition, what does `and` mean? Is it logical or bitwise? People confused by the difference between `&` and `&&` probably need something like `logand` and `bitand`.

Answer (score -5):

Ternary statements. They are generally much harder to read yet only save a few lines of code.

```
if (myCondition) {
    return firstAlternative();
}
return secondAlternative();
```

versus

```
return myCondition ? firstAlternative() : secondAlternative();
```

Comment: Ergh. If you are going to write it longhand, at least use an `else`.

Comment: Your example saves 3 out of 4 lines of code, i.e. 75%. This means that significantly more code will fit on my screen at a time. I think that is a pretty clear benefit. If you find statements involving the conditional operator “harder to read”, you probably just need to train yourself a bit more, and then you’ll have no trouble with them :)

Comment: In addition, there is no such thing as a "ternary statement". It's an expression and he who doesn't recognize the difference should go look for another job.

Comment: Perhaps this is better rectified by if expressions, ie `return if myCondition then firstAlternative else secondAlternative`, a la haskell/functional languages.